# What is difference between method `toHaveBeenCalled()` and `andCalledThrough()`

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

While using the Jasmine Spies, how different is `andCalledThrough()` method from `toHaveBeenCalled`, does it actually run the original method completely? Any ideal scenarios when I should use it?

Comment: Basically in mocking it is used to execute your mock function but 'andCalledThrough()' using this you call function and execute it also and 'toHaveBeenCalled' this only check whether function is in the file or not and getting called

Answer (score 2):

These are two different steps in spying on a function.

When you declare a `spy` on a function, before the function is called, you can attach some instructions to what should be done when the function is called. `and.callThrough()` means that the actual implementation will be used. Other options are `and.callFake()` and `and.returnValue()`, which allow you to mock a response and not use the actual implementation.

After the function you spied on was called, you can verify it was called using `expect` and `toHaveBeenCalled` and its variations.

Please refer to the [documentation](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-Spies).